# ffmpeg: How to assign an empty soundtrack to a video?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to build a short hunk of video from a machine-generated png.  This is working, but the video now needs to have a soundtrack (an [audio] field) for some of the other things I'm doing with it.  I don't actually want any sound in the video, so: is there a way to get ffmpeg to simply set up an empty soundtrack property in the video, perhaps as part of the call that creates the video?  I guess I could make an n-second long silent mp3 and bash it in, but is there a simpler / more direct way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @Alvaro for the links; one of these worked after a bit of massaging.  It does seem to be a two-step process: First make the soundtrack-less video and then do:

```
ffmpeg -ar 44100 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -channel_layout 2.1 
       -i /dev/zero -i in.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec libfaac -shortest out.mp4
```

The silence comes from `/dev/zero` and `-shortest` makes the process stop at the end of the video. Argument order is significant here; `-shortest` needs to be down near the output file spec.

This assumes that your ffmpeg installation has libfaac installed, which it might not.  But, otherwise, this seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to create a media file properly with audio and video stream. As far as i know, there is not a direct way.

If you know your video duration, first create the dummy audio and after when you create the video try to join the audio part.

In superuser, you can find more info [link1](https://superuser.com/questions/536547/add-silence-to-the-end-of-an-mp3/536587#536587) [link2](https://superuser.com/questions/350466/how-to-create-or-extract-a-silent-mp3-from-a-video-file-using-ffmpeg-or-mencoder)